# React Google Map API does not zoom in when user presses search for desired address

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-maps, api-design

Here is a snippet of the code, what needs to be changed so when the user clicks search it zooms closer to the address entered? Something similar to the google maps website. The overall aim is to have a similar search ability like that on the [google maps website](https://www.google.com/maps) in which when a user searches they are zoomed in to that location.

> ```
>    const AddressSearchDiv = styled.div`
>         position: relative;
>          svg {
>             position: absolute;
>             right: 10px;
>             top: 5px;
>           }
>         `;
>         const SeachInput = styled.input`
>           width: 100%;
>           border: 0;
>           background: none;
>           padding: 15px 40px 15px 15px;
>           font-size: 16px;
>           font-weight: 500;
>           outline: 0;
>           box-shadow: 0;
>           @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
>             padding: 20px 40px 20px 40px;
>           }
>         `;
>         const PlacesSearchBox = forwardRef(
>           (
>             { places, onLocationInputChange, onPlacesChange, onEnterKeyUp, value },
>             ref
>           ) => {
>             const [searchBox, setSearchBox] = useState(null);
>             const handlePlacesChanged = () => {
>               let address;
>               const place = searchBox.getPlaces()[0];
>               if (place.address_components) {
>                 address = mapAddressComponents(place.address_components);
>               }
>         
>               onPlacesChange(address, place);
>               onLocationInputChange({
>                 target: {
>                   value: place.formatted_address,
>                 },
>               });
>             };
>              useEffect(() => {
>               if (places.SearchBox && !searchBox) {
>                 setSearchBox(new places.SearchBox(ref.current));
>               }
>         
>               return () => {
>                 document.querySelector(".pac-container") &&
>                   document.querySelector(".pac-container").remove();
>               };
>             }, [places.SearchBox, searchBox, ref]);
>         
>             useEffect(() => {
>               if (searchBox) {
>                 searchBox.addListener("places_changed", handlePlacesChanged);
>               }
>               // eslint-disable-next-line
>             }, [searchBox]);
>                return (
>               <AddressSearchDiv>
>                 <SeachInput
>                   id="location-input"
>                   ref={ref}
>                   placeholder="City, State, or Zip code"
>                   tabIndex="2"
>                   type="text"
>                   onChange={onLocationInputChange}
>                   onKeyUp={onEnterKeyUp}
>                   value={value}
>                 />
>                 <MapPinIcon color="#333" size={24} />
>               </AddressSearchDiv>
>             );
>           }
>         );
>         
>         export default PlacesSearchBox;
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a state for your center and zoom. Everytime you choose a place from Autocomplete, you will change the state of your center to the chosen place and higher zoom level to view the place upclose.

Here is a [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/autocomple-sample-9yfts7?file=Map.js) and a code snippet below:

```
/*global google*/
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  withGoogleMap,
  withScriptjs,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker
} from "react-google-maps";
import Autocomplete from "react-google-autocomplete";
class Map extends Component {
  state = {
    center: { lat: 40.756795, lng: -73.954298 },
    zoom: 13
  };

  onPlaceSelected = place => {
    this.setState({
      center: place.geometry.location,
      zoom: 18
    });
  };

  render() {
    const Auto = props => (
      <Autocomplete
        style={{ width: "90%" }}
        onPlaceSelected={place => {
          console.log(place);
          this.onPlaceSelected(place);
        }}
        types={["(regions)"]}
      />
    );
    const GoogleMapExample = withGoogleMap(props => (
      <GoogleMap center={this.state.center} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
        <Marker position={this.state.center} />
      </GoogleMap>
    ));

    return (
      <div>
        <div style={{ margin: `15px` }}>
          <h3>Choose another destination</h3>
          <Auto />
        </div>
        <GoogleMapExample
          containerElement={<div style={{ height: `500px`, width: "500px" }} />}
          mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Map;
```

Comment: Thank you So much for your help and direction!  Greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome! You can accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Thanks! First of, kindly remove your email address in your question and comment for security and privacy.  As for your questions in the future, you can always post those questions here in Stack Overflow as there are many folks in this community that will be able to help you.